# How to use ImageWriter special options from barcode library in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, barcode

I've generated a barcode PNG image with the following code:

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

image_writer = ImageWriter()
ean = barcode.get('ean13', '123456789102', writer=image_writer)
filename = ean.save('ean13')
```

But I want to change the human readable text. I want to put it closer to the barcode and change the font size.

So. according to the library docs: https://python-barcode.readthedocs.io/en/stable/writers/index.html:

> All writer take the following options (specified as keyword arguments
> to Barcode.save(filename, options) or set via
> Writer.set_options(options), where options is a dictionary where keys
> are option names and values are option values to be set).

If I do this:

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

options = {
    'font_size': 20,
    'text_distance': 1.0,
}

image_writer = ImageWriter()
ean = barcode.get('ean13', '123456789102', writer=image_writer)
filename = ean.save('ean13', options)
```

It works as expected. The problem is that in the future I won't want to generate an image file stored on disk, and `write` method does not accept options.

So I'm trying the other way, using `set_options`, which theoretically works for every kind of `Writer` as they inherit from `BaseWriter`, but if I do this:

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

options = {
    'format': 'PNG',
    'font_size': 20,
    'text_distance': 1.0,
}

image_writer = ImageWriter().set_options(options)
ean = barcode.get('ean13', '123456789102', writer=image_writer)
filename = ean.save('ean13')
```

Not only I don't get what I want but the generated image file is a SVG.

Why is this happening? Any ideas of how can I achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

did you try using render?

```
from barcode import Code128
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

render_options = {
                "module_width": 0.25,
                "module_height": 6,
                "write_text": False,
                "module_width": 0.25,
                "quiet_zone": 0.1,
            }

 barcode=Code128("123456789",writer=ImageWriter()).render(render_options)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).